# Initializing std::array<char,x> member in constructor using string literal. GCC bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, compiler-bug, stdarray

The following example initializing a `std::array <char, N>` member in a constructor using a string literal doesn't compile on GCC 4.8 but compiles using Clang 3.4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct A {
  std::array<char, 4> x; 
  A(std::array<char, 4> arr) : x(arr) {}
};


int main() {
    // works with Clang 3.4, error in GCC 4.8.
    // It should be the equivalent of "A a ({'b','u','g','\0'});"
    A a ({"bug"});
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.x.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << a.x[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

On first impression it looks like a GCC bug. I feel it should compile as we can initialize a `std::array<char, N>` directly with a string literal. For example:

```
std::array<char, 4> test = {"bug"}; //works
```

I would be interested to see what the Standard says about this.

Comment: Compiles cleanly with clang 3.5 (trunk 200501) with `-Wall -Wextra`  and works as expected. The [error messages with gcc online](http://ideone.com/A0Wza7).

Comment: FWIW, `A a (std::array<char, 4>{"bug"});` is accepted by GCC, so "no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::array<char, 4u>'" looks very strange to me.

Comment: I don't understand why {{"bug"}} works, you're asking for a 4-sized char array, not for a string (that's a different beast). Perhaps clang is being smart and fixing the user's code

Comment: There is a special rule in the standard that allows you to initialise a `char[N]` from a string literal. I assume this rule is coming in to play. [See here](http://ideone.com/G306q7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is valid; this is a bug in gcc.

Here's a simpler program that demonstrates the bug (I've replaced `std::array<char, 4>` with `S` and got rid of `A`, as we can demonstrate the bug just in function return (this makes the analysis simpler, as we don't have to worry about constructor overloading):

```
struct S { char c[4]; };
S f() { return {"xxx"}; }
```

Here we have a destination object of type `S` that is *copy-initialized* (8.5p15) from the *braced-init-list* `{"xxx"}`, so the object is *list-initialized* (8.5p17b1).  `S` is an aggregate (8.5.1p1) so aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.4p3b1).  In aggregate initialization, the member `c` is *copy-initialized* from the corresponding *initializer-clause* `"xxx"` (8.5.1p2).  We now return to 8.5p17 with destination object of type `char[4]` and initializer the string literal `"xxx"`, so 8.5p17b3 refers us to 8.5.2 and the elements of the `char` array are initialized by the successive characters of the string (8.5.2p1).

Note that gcc is fine with the copy-initialization `S s = {"xxx"};` while breaking on various forms of copy- and direct-initialization; argument passing (including to constructors), function return, and base- and member-initialization:

```
struct S { char c[4]; };
S f() { return {"xxx"}; }
void g(S) { g({"xxx"}); }
auto p = new S({"xxx"});
struct T { S s; T(): s({"xxx"}) {} };
struct U: S { U(): S({"xxx"}) {} };
S s({"xxx"});
```

The last is particularly interesting as it indicates that this may be related to [bug 43453](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43453).

Comment: Are you sure that the Standard treats `array<char, N>` specially in that it allows initializing with a braced enclosed string literal? IIRC, it does not specify the internal representation, so it seems to me that it's not safe to assume that you can initialize it with `= { string-literal }`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb. AFAIK 'array<char, N>' is a thin wrapper around a 'char [N]' which itself can be initialized with a string literal so consequently it appears logical for 'array<char, N>' to also be initialized using a string literal. However, although it appears logical to me it is ultimately up to the Standard. If people are told to prefer 'std::array' over built-in C arrays I feel it is important that string literal initialization is supported.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb you're right, of course; 23.3.2.1p2 only requires `array` to be an aggregate that accepts copy-initialization from a brace-enclosed initializer list; the `T elemens[N]` member is for exposition only, so it's possible to conceive of a class layout for `array<char, N>` that doesn't contain directly a `char[N]` array member.

Comment: @ecatmur How else could `std::array` be implemented if it didn't contain a `char[N]` member?

Comment: @Ricky65 `struct array { struct Elem { T elem } elems[N] }` would satisfy the aggregate and initialization requirement; it might need a little help to satisfy contiguity but the implementation would be able to provide the necessary guarantees.

Comment: @ecatmur The standard requires support for initialization from a initializer-list of a type convertible to `T`, not just for `T` directly. Consider `struct S { operator int() { return 0; } template <typename T> operator T() = delete; };`, and then `array<int, 1>{S()}`. That would break on your implementation.

Comment: @hvd very good point - that means that `array` can't wrap its elements in a class type.  There is though the possibility of an "optimisation" for small `N` where the elements are distinct members e.g. `template<> array<char, 2> { char c; char d; };` (the implementation would be able to supply appropriate layout guarantees).

Comment: @ecatmur That's sneaky, but does look valid. The implementation would need to ensure that it still fully supports pointer arithmetic (`&array[0] + 2 == &array[2]`): that is guaranteed by the standard, so an implementation cannot declare such code undefined just because the implementation of `array` does not use an array. Then again, the (non-normative) note in [array.overview] "The member variable `elems` is shown for exposition only, to emphasize that `array` is a class aggregate. The name `elems` is not part of array’s interface." can be read to imply that its type is part of the interface.

Comment: @ecatmur To clarify, in `struct S { int i; int j; };`, even if `&i + 1 == &j`, accessing `(&i)[1]` is still invalid (in C, anyway, and I don't think C++ opened this up).

Comment: @hvd that doesn't have to be invalid if the implementation feels like making it valid. that's the good of undefined behavior. But, anyway, there's still `array<char, 1>`

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You're taking that out of context, I did mean invalid as far as the standard is concerned. The point was specifically that in order for that implementation of `array` to be valid, the implementation would need to specifically support such constructs. :) That said, I really like `array<char, 1>`, because that wouldn't even need a malicious implementation to not contain an array as its member.