# Are there aggregate initialization differences between std::vector and std::array?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++, list-initialization, aggregate-initialization

In `std::array`, we can simply state like this

```
std::array<std::array<char,10>, 2> arr_gcc{ 
    "abcdefghi", "abcdefghi"
};
```

Or even in clang with -Wall, they just need somewhat more explicit expression, having to add some more subobject braces like this

```
std::array<std::array<char,10>, 2> arr_clang_wall_favor{{
    {"abcdefghi"}, {"abcdefghi"}
}};
```

When it comes to `std::vector`, one way is to explicitly construct each subobject like his

```
// This works in both clang and gcc
std::vector vec{
    std::array<char,10>{"abcdefghi"}, std::array<char,10>{"abcdefghi"}
};
```

If we try to do in aggregate like this

```
std::vector<std::array<char,10> > vec_clang{{
    {"abcdefghi"}, {"abcdefghi"}
}};
```

It works only in clang but is an error in gcc as

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:21:6: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::array<char, 10>, std::allocator<std::array<char, 10> > >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
     }};
      ^
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/vector:64:0,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_vector.h:411:2: note: candidate: template<class _InputIterator, class> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&)
  vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
  ^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_vector.h:411:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:21:6: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
     }};
      ^
```

---

Are there aggregate initialization differences between `std::vector` and `std::array`? If yes, Why?

By the standard, is gcc supposed to compile that aggregate like clang does?

[godbolt.org/g/TRZHnu](https://godbolt.org/g/TRZHnu)

Comment: `std::vector` isn't an aggregate.... so...

Comment: "List Initialization", if you've never heard of it...

Comment: @NickyC Should I change the question to list initialization?

Comment: Hard to say. Not sure.

Comment: Passing explicitly what you claim that the vector contains, i.e. `char[10]` seems to work fine everywhere: https://ideone.com/BzjZr6

Comment: @KillzoneKid There seems so so many initialization rules we have indeed!

Comment: For your last example, the most reasonable way is to use two layers of braces while three layers is also valid (GCC rejects both two-layer version and three-layer version). This is a GCC bug, possibly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555026/initializing-stdarraychar-x-member-in-constructor-using-string-literal-gcc).